# Azure Traffic Manager / AWS Route 53 policy failover functionality in Google Cloud (GCP)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-route53, terraform-provider-gcp, azure-traffic-manager

I am unable to find the proper documentation to create a failover scenario similar to the one offered by Azure Traffic Manager and AWS Route 53 Traffic Policy in Google Cloud (DNS based). Is such kind of functionality even possible in google cloud?

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud does not offer DNS failover features similar to Route 53 or Azure Traffic Manager.

In Google Cloud, a load balancer and health checks are deployed instead of DNS server failover features.

Because of DNS global caching of resource records, DNS failover is often not a good solution. Load balancers are a better location to implement traffic management. The load balancer and instance group management have far more details about the underlying services to make good decisions. DNS has only a few options to make management decisions.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The services that I want to provide HA are external services(backends), I can only see that the Load balancer(classic) is supporting the external backends but it doesn't have a health check enabled when I am trying to configure it, not sure if I am missing something here.. Could you please point me to a right resource?

Comment: @MaheshPalavalli - For your next question please create a new post.

Comment: Sure @John-hanley, here is the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72913334/gcp-dns-loadbalancer-failover-for-external-services